# using a class defined in dll without referencing it C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a mod for a unity game. This mod is a single .cs file. I plan to use xml functions from System.Xml but it's not referenced in the game. How do I implement System.Xml in my .cs file without referencing it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to compile your CS file before it is being loaded into the app, you have to reference it yourself and the compiler will include the reference. Since `System.Xml` is an assembly that resides in the GAC, it will load without issues, even if the app doesn't use it.

If you just load the code file into the app it might work or not. Depending on how the Unity app would load your CS file and where and how you intend to use the assembly, you could be helped by attaching to the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event handler and resolve the assembly at run-time.

If that seems to be hard, you could even create a code file that creates an assembly on run-time and load that one into the app just after you have loaded the `System.Xml` assembly from your bootstrapper code.

Comment: Thank you alot for answering. I just put code file into corresponding foldier, for it to work, but it sadly doesn't resolve reference. I will try AssemblyResolve and look, if it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new with the C# so I don't know how to do any of that. I would be very greatfull if you could suplement some code for me to get how to use assembly. I guess I could load file of System.Xml.dll directly with Assembly.LoadFile but I have no idea what to do with this assembly next. Please, could you explain, or show the code/book/post where I can see how to use classes from assembly?